# Spine.js IE6 Support

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, internet-explorer-6, spine.js

So I've been looking at [Spine.js](http://maccman.github.com/spine/) recently as an alternative to Backbone. However, in the documentation is states:

> Works in all major browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE >= 7)

then in the comments on [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-apps-spinejs/) page some one says:

> Spine doesn't seem to run in IE6 or IE7... Maybe even other Internet
>   Explorers.  Shouldn't this be pointed out? Backbone runs fine with
>   these. Am I just missing something?

reply:

> Maybe because of json? "If you're using an older browser which doesn't
>   have native JSON support (i.e. IE 7), you'll need to include json2.js
>   which adds legacy support." (from the docs)

This is literally ALL the information i could find on the subject. Does anyone know if ie6 is at all supported? If not I'm afraid I will not be able to use it...

Comment: IE6 is closing in on 10 years old, I wouldn't expect much support from anyone these days

Comment: the joys of coding commercial web apps :)

Comment: I'm a developer for .com, we support ie7+ at this point.. Google doesn't even support IE7 - can't even use their google+ +1 code..

Comment: still, the application should still retain core functionality in ie6 which wouldn't be possible if the mvc framework falls apart.

Comment: heehehe, I guess my official suggestion is to get into an argument with whoever still thinks supporting IE6 makes sense :P

Comment: Come up with a cost estimate (in both development time, QA time and bug fix time) for supporting IE6 and then find out if anyone in the company can justify spending that much extra dough to support that few browsers.  It's highly unlikely that supporting IE6 makes economic sense any more.

Comment: all I can say is, i wish... Either way I think we're a little off topic. Does anyone have an answer to the original question?

Comment: IE6 isn't even supported by Microsoft anymore. Simply don't bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that spine.js works on IE7 - we don't have IE6 as a requirement nor any IE6 tests machines, so I can't comment on IE6 support.

I would suggest running a quick test, using it takes under an hour to get a simple app running that you can verify things on.

Comment: Same over here. ie7 is min requirement and it works. The only thing that does not work is the logging method in any IE <= 9 (haven't tested in ie10).